# Square integrable for universal approximation

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, approximation-theory, dense-subspaces

Let's consider square-integrable functions $f \in L^2\left(I_n\right)$ with the definition of the $\textit{discriminatory}$:

$\textbf{Definition:}$. The activation function $\sigma$ is called discriminatory in $L^2$ sense if:

(i) $0 \leq \sigma \leq 1$;

(ii) if $g \in L^2\left(I_n\right)$ such that
$$
\int_{I_n} \sigma\left(w^T x+\theta\right) g(x) d x=0, \quad \forall w \in \mathbb{R}^n, \theta \in \mathbb{R}
$$
then $g=0$ almost everywhere.

$\textbf{Lemma:}$ Let $\sigma$ be a discriminatory function in $L^2$ sense. Then, the finite sums of the form
$$
G(x)=\sum_{j=1}^N \alpha_j \sigma\left(w_j^T x+\theta_j\right), \quad \forall w_j \in \mathbb{R}^n, \theta_j, \alpha_j \in \mathbb{R}
$$
are dense in $L^2\left(I_n\right)$.

#### Proof

I want to prove this by contradiction. Assume that the set of such finite sums is not dense in $L^2(I_n)$. This implies a function $f \in L^2(I_n)$ which cannot be approximated arbitrarily closely by any function of the form $G(x)$.

Given the properties of $L^2$ spaces, we can consider the orthogonal complement of the span of the functions of the form $G(x)$. If our set is not dense, then there exists a non-zero function $g \in L^2(I_n)$ orthogonal to every function of the form $G(x)$. Mathematically, this means:
$$\int_{I_n} g(x) \sum_{j=1}^N \alpha_j \sigma(w_j^T x + \theta_j) dx = 0, \quad \forall w_j \in \mathbb{R}^n, \theta_j, \alpha_j \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Due to linearity of integration, this simplifies to:
$$\sum_{j=1}^N \alpha_j \int_{I_n} g(x) \sigma(w_j^T x + \theta_j) dx = 0, \quad \forall w_j \in \mathbb{R}^n, \theta_j, \alpha_j \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Since $\alpha_j$ are arbitrary, for this equality to hold for all choices of $\alpha_j$, it must be that each integral itself is zero:
$$\int_{I_n} g(x) \sigma(w^T x + \theta) dx = 0, \quad \forall w \in \mathbb{R}^n, \theta \in \mathbb{R}.$$

However, by our assumption, $\sigma$ is discriminatory in the $L^2$ sense. This means that the only function $g(x)$ that satisfies the above condition for all $w$ and $\theta$ is the zero function, $g = 0$ almost everywhere in $I_n$.

This is a contradiction because we assumed that $g$ is non-zero in $L^2(I_n)$. Therefore, our initial assumption that the set of such finite sums is not dense in $L^2(I_n)$ must be false. This implies that the finite sums of the form $G(x)$ are indeed dense in $L^2(I_n)$, completing the proof.

I wanted to know whether all these assumptions and proof logic are rigorous enough or require additional procedures to be completed. Any form of suggestions, detailed analysis would be very appreciated.

Comment: Everything looks right to me.

Comment: @DavidGao Thank you for the comment. I wanted to make sure my proof is fundamentally rigorous and mathematically detailed, especially on the Hilbert space structure of $L^2(I_{n})$ and the properties of linearity of integration where the coefficients $\alpha_{j}$ become all zero. Should I explain more accurately those specific points and how to obtain the first equation from the properties of $L^2$ spaces?

Comment: @DavidGao It seems to make me a bit afraid that I have claimed all these properties without proper, mathematically rigorous proof.

Comment: If this is some kind of homework assignment, I can’t really speak to whether your professor would consider this detailed or rigorous enough. That, you have to ask them. But I would say this is good enough in the sense that anyone with appropriate background would be convinced of your claim and that your proof entails your claim after reading your proof, which is the reasonable standard for mathematical rigor in my book.

Comment: @DavidGao Thanks very much once again for your comment! It is good to know that additional mathematical proofs are not necessary in my proof. If proper definitions of Hilbert spaces and the orthogonal properties of its complement are presented clearly, then everyone should be able to understand it fully!~

Comment: Some comments for those who came after bounty has been offered: I need systematic, rigorous math-specific proof for this problem. I outlined some of my progress but I personally want to see very math-detailed solution, can be possibly based on my current posted one!

Comment: @DavidGao If any further mathematical descriptions need to be included in my post, you may post them as a solution if you want!

Comment: @DavidGao Do you want to draft a possible solution? The bounty is expiring in one day but if you feel you have some substantial amount of progress, I can give you the points.

Comment: As I said before, your solution is perfectly fine to me, and is rigorous enough to my taste. Quite honestly, if I were the one writing the proof of this fact I would have likely included even *less* details. So there’s really nothing for me to write in an answer, unless you have a very specific step in the proof that you’d like me to address.